# Run a task once after specific time - node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cron

So I'm developing a platform using Node.js where users can have gift cards, initially a card is inactive and in order to use it they should activate it. Once they activate it, they have N minutes/seconds to use it or it will be inactive again.

Now the question that I have is that, what is the best way to implement such a feature? Would it be simply a setTimeout? or it shall be a cron job?.

I'm thinking that if I use setTimeout, will that cause some issues for the server since there are many users?. And for the cron.job, this task is simply one-time, so I'm not sure if it is the right choice.

Any ideas?

Comment: In my opinion, the best way would be to add a new gift card entry to the database, flag it with: not activated, and set the time of creation. That way, on the time of activation, you may compare the time of creation with the time of activation. If its within your accepted timeframe, you flag it as active. If not, you reject it.

Comment: @StephanBakkelundValois well...that is not technically what I want, but you brought a great idea to my mind. Thanks!

Comment: I think this is a good way of doing this. If something happens with the server (it goes down), you don't loose the state of the gift card. The state of the gift card will be stored safely inside the db